# Render PDF in a new window from Base64 data using react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

Can someone please tell me how to render base64 content as a PDF in a new window. Below is my code.

```
<Document file={`data:application/pdf;base64,${this.state.base64}`} externalLinkTarget="_blank"
                    onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoadSuccess} >
                    <Page onRenderSuccess={() => alert('Rendered the page!')} />
                </Document>
```